# After migrating a site using from Apache to IIS7, jumpmenus output URLs with unicode instead of desired characters. How do I restore desired behavior?

Tags: php, mysql, windows, iis-7

After migrating site from Apache to IIS7 (Windows Server 2008 R2), Javascript jumpmenus output "%2F" instead of "/"  and "%3A" instead of ":" . Also  the following shows as output in the URL "?stage2=" . When on Apache the URL came out fine. Please help..?.
..?...?

```
<form name="doublecombo" target="_parent">
                In:
                <select style="position: relative; top: -58px; left: 55px;" class="jumpmenu" size="1" onChange="redirect(this.options.selectedIndex)">
                  <option>select a category...</option>
                  <option>Grow Stores</option>
                  <option>Dispensaries</option>
                  <option>Cannibas Clubs</option>
                  <option>Physicians</option>
                  <option>State Marijuana Laws</option>
                </select>
                <br>
                <select style="position: relative; top: -64px; left: 55px;" name="stage2" size="1" class="jumpmenu" >
                  <option value="">select a state...</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/alabama-grow-stores" >Alabama</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/alaska-grow-stores">Alaska</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/arizona-grow-stores">Arizona</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/arkansas-grow-stores">Arkansas</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/california-grow-stores">California</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/colorado-grow-stores">Colorado</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/connecticut-grow-stores">Connecticut</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/delaware-grow-stores">Delaware</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/district-of-columbia-grow-stores">District of Columbia</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/florida-grow-stores">Florida</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/georgia-grow-stores">Georgia</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/hawaii-grow-stores">Hawaii</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/idaho-grow-stores">Idaho</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/illinois-grow-stores">Illinois</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/indiana-grow-stores">Indiana</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/iowa-grow-stores">Iowa</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/kansas-grow-stores">Kansas</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/kentucky-grow-stores">Kentucky</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/louisiana-grow-stores">Louisiana</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/maine-grow-stores">Maine</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/maryland-grow-stores">Maryland</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/massachusetts-grow-stores">Massachusetts</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/michigan-grow-stores">Michigan</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/minnesota-grow-stores">Minnesota</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/mississippi-grow-stores">Mississippi</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/missouri-grow-stores">Missouri</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/montana-grow-stores">Montana</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/nebraska-grow-stores">Nebraska</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/nevada-grow-stores">Nevada</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/new-hampshire-grow-stores">New Hampshire</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/new-jersey-grow-stores">New Jersey</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/new-mexico-grow-stores">New Mexico</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/new-york-grow-stores">New York</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/north-carolina-grow-stores">North Carolina</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/north-dakota-grow-stores">North Dakota</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/ohio-grow-stores">Ohio</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/oklahoma-grow-stores">Oklahoma</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/oregon-grow-stores">Oregon</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/pennsylvania-grow-stores">Pennsylvania</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/rhode-island-grow-stores">Rhode Island</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/south-carolina-grow-stores">South Carolina</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/south-dakota-grow-stores">South Dakota</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/tennessee-grow-stores">Tennessee</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/texas-grow-stores">Texas</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/utah-grow-stores">Utah</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/vermont-grow-stores">Vermont</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/virginia-grow-stores">Virginia</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/washington-grow-stores">Washington</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/west-virginia-grow-stores">West Virginia</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/wisconsin-grow-stores">Wisconsin</option>
                  <option value="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/wyoming-grow-stores">Wyoming</option>
                </select>
                <div style="position: relative; top: -58px; left: 70px;">
                  <div class="div38-160">
                    <input type="image" class="sprite38" src="http://mymedicinalgarden.org/buttons/go/go.gif" ONCLICK="go()" />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
              <script>
<!--

var groups=document.doublecombo.example.options.length
var group=new Array(groups)
for (i=0; i<groups; i++)
group[i]=new Array()

group[0][0]=new Option("select state...","")

group[1][0]=new Option("Alabama","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/alabama-grow-stores/")
group[1][1]=new Option("Alaska","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/alaska-grow-stores/")
group[1][2]=new Option("Arizona","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/arizona-grow-stores/")
group[1][3]=new Option("Arkansas","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/arkansas-grow-stores/")
group[1][4]=new Option("Arizona","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/arizona-grow-stores/")
group[1][5]=new Option("California","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/california-grow-stores/")
group[1][6]=new Option("Colorado","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/colorado-grow-stores/")
group[1][7]=new Option("Connecticut","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/connecticut-grow-stores/")
group[1][8]=new Option("Delaware","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/delaware-grow-stores/")
group[1][9]=new Option("District of Columbia","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/district-of-columbia-grow-stores/")
group[1][10]=new Option("Florida","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/florida-grow-stores/")
group[1][11]=new Option("Georgia","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/georgia-grow-stores/")
group[1][12]=new Option("Hawaii","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/hawaii-grow-stores/")
group[1][13]=new Option("Idaho","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/idaho-grow-stores/")
group[1][14]=new Option("Illinois","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/illinois-grow-stores/")
group[1][15]=new Option("Indiana","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/indiana-grow-stores/")
group[1][16]=new Option("Iowa","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/iowa-grow-stores/")
group[1][17]=new Option("Kansas","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/kansas-grow-stores/")
group[1][18]=new Option("Kentucky","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/kentucky-grow-stores/")
group[1][19]=new Option("Louisiana","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/louisiana-grow-stores/")
group[1][20]=new Option("Maine","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/maine-grow-stores/")
group[1][21]=new Option("Maryland","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/maryland-grow-stores/")
group[1][22]=new Option("Massachusetts","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/massachusetts-grow-stores/")
group[1][23]=new Option("Michigan","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/michigan-grow-stores/")
group[1][24]=new Option("Minnesota","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/minnesota-grow-stores/")
group[1][25]=new Option("Mississippi","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/mississippi-grow-stores/")
group[1][26]=new Option("Missouri","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/missouri-grow-stores/")
group[1][27]=new Option("Montana","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/montana-grow-stores/")
group[1][28]=new Option("Nebraska","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/nebraska-grow-stores/")
group[1][29]=new Option("Nevada","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/nevada-grow-stores/")
group[1][30]=new Option("New Hampshire","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/new-hampshire-grow-stores/")
group[1][31]=new Option("New Jersey","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/new-jersey-grow-stores/")
group[1][32]=new Option("New Mexico","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/new-mexico-grow-stores/")
group[1][33]=new Option("New York","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/new-york-grow-stores/")
group[1][34]=new Option("North Carolina","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/north-carolina-grow-stores/")
group[1][35]=new Option("North Dakota","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/north-dakota-grow-stores/")
group[1][36]=new Option("Ohio","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/ohio-grow-stores/")
group[1][37]=new Option("Oklahoma","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/oklahoma-grow-stores/")
group[1][38]=new Option("Oregon","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/oregon-grow-stores/")
group[1][39]=new Option("Pennsylvania","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/pennsylvania-grow-stores/")
group[1][40]=new Option("Rhode Island","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/rhode-island-grow-stores/")
group[1][41]=new Option("South Carolina","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/south-carolina-grow-stores/")
group[1][42]=new Option("South Dakota","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/south-dakota-grow-stores/")
group[1][43]=new Option("Tennessee","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/tennessee-grow-stores/")
group[1][44]=new Option("Texas","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/texas-grow-stores/")
group[1][45]=new Option("Utah","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/utah-grow-stores/")
group[1][46]=new Option("Vermont","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/vermont-grow-stores/")
group[1][47]=new Option("Virginia","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/virginia-grow-stores/")
group[1][48]=new Option("Washington","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/washington-grow-stores/")
group[1][49]=new Option("West Virginia","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/west-virginia-grow-stores/")
group[1][50]=new Option("Wisconsin","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/wisconsin-grow-stores/")
group[1][51]=new Option("Wyoming","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/wyoming-grow-stores/")



group[2][0]=new Option("Alaska","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/alaska-dispensaries/")
group[2][1]=new Option("Arizona","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/arizona-dispensaries/")
group[2][2]=new Option("California","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/california-dispensaries/")
group[2][3]=new Option("Colorado","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/colorado-dispensaries/")
group[2][4]=new Option("Delaware","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/delaware-dispensaries/")
group[2][5]=new Option("Hawaii","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/hawaii-dispensaries/")
group[2][6]=new Option("Maine","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/maine-dispensaries/")
group[2][7]=new Option("Michigan","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/michigan-dispensaries/")
group[2][8]=new Option("Montana","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/montana-dispensaries/")
group[2][9]=new Option("Nevada","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/nevada-dispensaries/")
group[2][10]=new Option("New Jersey","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/new-jersey-dispensaries/")
group[2][11]=new Option("New Mexico","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/new-mexico-dispensaries/")
group[2][12]=new Option("Oregon","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/oregon-dispensaries/")
group[2][13]=new Option("Rhode Island","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/rhode-island-dispensaries/")
group[2][14]=new Option("Vermont","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/vermont-dispensaries/")
group[2][15]=new Option("Washington","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/washington-dispensaries/")
group[2][16]=new Option("","------------------------------------------------------------------")
group[2][17]=new Option("District of Columbia","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/distsrict-of-columbia-dispensaries/")




group[3][0]=new Option("Alaska","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/alaska-cannabis-clubs/")
group[3][1]=new Option("Arizona","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/arizona-cannabis-clubs/")
group[3][2]=new Option("California","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/california-cannabis-clubs/")
group[3][3]=new Option("Colorado","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/colorado-cannabis-clubs/")
group[3][4]=new Option("Delaware","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/delaware-cannabis-clubs/")
group[3][5]=new Option("Hawaii","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/hawaii-cannabis-clubs/")
group[3][6]=new Option("Maine","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/maine-cannabis-clubs/")
group[3][7]=new Option("Michigan","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/michigan-cannabis-clubs/")
group[3][8]=new Option("Montana","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/montana-cannabis-clubs/")
group[3][9]=new Option("Nevada","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/nevada-cannabis-clubs/")
group[3][10]=new Option("New Jersey","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/new-jersey-cannabis-clubs/")
group[3][11]=new Option("New Mexico","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/new-mexico-cannabis-clubs/")
group[3][12]=new Option("Oregon","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/oregon-cannabis-clubs/")
group[3][13]=new Option("Rhode Island","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/rhode-island-cannabis-clubs/")
group[3][14]=new Option("Vermont","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/vermont-cannabis-clubs/")
group[3][15]=new Option("Washington","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/washington-cannabis-clubs/")
group[3][16]=new Option("","------------------------------------------------------------------")
group[3][17]=new Option("District of Columbia","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/distsrict-of-columbia-cannabis-clubs/")





group[4][0]=new Option("Alaska","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/alaska-physicians/")
group[4][1]=new Option("Arizona","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/arizona-physicians/")
group[4][2]=new Option("California","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/california-physicians/")
group[4][3]=new Option("Colorado","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/colorado-physicians/")
group[4][4]=new Option("Delaware","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/delaware-physicians/")
group[4][5]=new Option("Hawaii","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/hawaii-physicians/")
group[4][6]=new Option("Maine","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/maine-physicians/")
group[4][7]=new Option("Michigan","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/michigan-physicians/")
group[4][8]=new Option("Montana","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/montana-physicians/")
group[4][9]=new Option("Nevada","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/nevada-physicians/")
group[4][10]=new Option("New Jersey","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/new-jersey-physicians/")
group[4][11]=new Option("New Mexico","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/new-mexico-physicians/")
group[4][12]=new Option("Oregon","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/oregon-physicians/")
group[4][13]=new Option("Rhode Island","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/rhode-island-physicians/")
group[4][14]=new Option("Vermont","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/vermont-physicians/")
group[4][15]=new Option("Washington","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/washington-physicians/")
group[4][16]=new Option("","------------------------------------------------------------------")
group[4][17]=new Option("District of Columbia","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/distsrict-of-columbia-organizations/")



group[5][0]=new Option("Alaska","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/marijuana-law-alaska/")
group[5][1]=new Option("Arizona","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/marijuana-law-arizona/")
group[5][2]=new Option("California","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/marijuana-law-california/")
group[5][3]=new Option("Colorado","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/marijuana-law-colorado/")
group[5][4]=new Option("Delaware","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/marijuana-law-delaware/")
group[5][5]=new Option("Hawaii","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/marijuana-law-hawaii")
group[5][6]=new Option("Maine","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/marijuana-law-maine/")
group[5][7]=new Option("Michigan","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/marijuana-law-michigan/")
group[5][8]=new Option("Montana","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/marijuana-law-montana/")
group[5][9]=new Option("Nevada","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/marijuana-law-nevada/")
group[5][10]=new Option("New Jersey","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/marijuana-law-new-jersey/")
group[5][11]=new Option("New Mexico","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/marijuana-law-new-mexico/")
group[5][12]=new Option("Oregon","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/marijuana-law-oregon/")
group[5][13]=new Option("Rhode Island","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/marijuana-law-rhode-island/")
group[5][14]=new Option("Vermont","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/marijuana-law-vermont/")
group[5][15]=new Option("Washington","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/marijuana-law-washington/")
group[5][16]=new Option("","------------------------------------------------------------------")
group[5][17]=new Option("District of Columbia","http://mymedicinalgarden.org/marijuana-law-distsrict-of-columbia/")




var temp=document.doublecombo.stage2

function redirect(x){
for (m=temp.options.length-1;m>0;m--)
temp.options[m]=null
for (i=0;i<group[x].length;i++){
temp.options[i]=new Option(group[x][i].text,group[x][i].value)
}
temp.options[0].selected=true
}

function go(){
location=temp.options[temp.selectedIndex].value  

}



//-->
</script>
```

Comment: That is a valid answer, but one that deters learning and constrains one to a single environment. But point taken...

Comment: What exactly is being output from where? What does the source code look like and where do the URLs come from?

Comment: code has been added to original post